# Loading a wordpress shortcode in JS

Tags: php

I made an ajax call to a php function, that should render a shortcode:

```
public function loadShortCode(){
    $shortcode = do_shortcode('[elementor-template id="2635"]', false );
    wp_send_json($shortcode);
}
```

Sadly it just returns it as text "[elementor-template id="2635"]". Is it possible to get the html from the shortcode and print it somewhere via JS? It is being done in a .js file, so I can't use php echo manipulation.

I already tried this, but this just returns the shortcode as text in my html

```
const loadShortCode = async () => {
const response = await fetch(wp.ajax_url + "?action=loadShortCode", {
    method: "POST",
});

return response.json();
```

}

```
(async() => {
    const response = await loadShortCode();
    console.log(response);
    membershipTypesContainer.innerHTML = response;
})();
 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_loadShortCode', [__CLASS__, 'loadShortCode']);
        add_action('wp_ajax_loadShortCode', [__CLASS__, 'loadShortCode']);
```

Comment: How are you making the AJAX request? And how are you registering the callback? Are you using admin-ajax.php or the REST API?

Comment: add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_loadShortCode', [__CLASS__, 'loadShortCode']);
        add_action('wp_ajax_loadShortCode', [__CLASS__, 'loadShortCode']);  and const loadShortCode = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(wp.ajax_url + "?action=loadShortCode", {
        method: "POST",
    });

    return response.json();
}

(async() => {
    const response = await loadShortCode();
    console.log(response);
    membershipTypesContainer.innerHTML = response;
})();

Comment: https://pastebin.com/NcHE472S

Comment: Please just add any additional code to the question.

Comment: My **guess** is that the shortcode `elementor-template` isn't registered during AJAX calls. (or you're using an invalid shortcode).

Comment: @PaulG. huh i don't really get it

Comment: @Jan When you enter a shortcode in a post, it doesn't display the content by magic. It must be "registered" with WordPress so that when WP sees it, it can use the registered shortcode function to process the shortcode. There is therefore code within Elementor to register the shortcode with WordPress. If that code to register the shortcode only executes when you load a post or page, and not, for example when AJAX is called, then WordPress will see the shortcode you've sent, not have any handler registered for it, and so not do anything with it.